# On the sequence of orthonormal basic

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces, orthonormal

I have a question :

Let $0 \leq a \leq b \leq +\infty $, supposing that ${\phi_n(x,t)}_{n \geq 0}$ be the orthonormal basis on $L^2(a,b)$ respected to $x$. If there exist a sequence $\psi_n(t)$ such that $\sum_{n}\psi_n(t)\phi_n(x,t) = 0$, then can we imply
 $\psi_n(t) = 0$ for all $n$ ?. If not, can we give a counter example ?

---

In fact, I would like to change the question more complicatedly. That is

Let $0 \leq a \leq b \leq +\infty $, supposing that ${\phi_n(x,t)}_{n \geq 0}$ be the orthonormal basis on $L^2(a,b)$ respected to $x$. If there exist a sequence $\psi_n(t)$ and $x_0$ such that $\sum_{n}\psi_n(t)\phi_n(x_0,t) = 0$, then can we imply

$\psi_n(t) = 0$ for all $n$ ?. If not, can we give a counter example ?

Comment: What exactly are you assuming? Do you mean that $(\phi_n (x,t))_{n \geq 0}$ is an orthonormal basis of $L^2((a,b))$ for every $t$? In this case, it is not hard to show that the answer to your question is "yes".

Comment: Yes, it is for all $t$. How to answer "yes" ?